# In single page application, how to store data and get data after refresh the page

Tags: javascript, local-storage, single-page-application, vue.js

Recently I have a problem with how to store data on a single page application.

I want to ask how to store data and get the data back after refresh page in a Single Page Application.

For example, I get 'user name' and it is shown on the navigation bar, but after I refresh the page, the 'user name' is gone. The 'user name' is a javascript variable.

Before refresh

[image: before refresh]

After refresh

[image]

Could anyone give some suggestions about how and where to store the data ?

In the localStorage or somewhere else? What should be a standard or proper way?

Also, another way is fetch data again from server every time after the page refresh, is this a proper way?

BTW, I am using Vue.js.

Thanks

Comment: `localStorage` seems like a good idea. Why not try it?

Comment: It depends. How is the data being used? There are many storage mechanisms for different uses. Cookies, localStorage, sessionStorage, databases, query parameters, to name a few.

Comment: you can use local storage, but you should decide when to invalidate data. in your case user may rename himself in another browser and you will never know about it

Comment: localStorage is very long term, almost permanent. sessionStorage is good until the browser window or tab is closed, and could be more appropriate for username-specific sessions.

Comment: @tcooc I am using JWT to do the authentication and I store the response token in localStorage. I am not sure this is a proper way or not. The 'user name' is used to display purpose only; however when it comes to a form, if user accidently  refreshed the page before submit, all data may lost. How to save those data or current state ? Because I've never done a SPA before, any suggestion about SPA is useful for me. Thanks very much.

Comment: @YIYANG Then cookies are your best choice. Using session/localStorage is a serious security problem as well as complicating the authentication process. Java should already have many libraries that handle authentication using cookies.

Answer (score 1):

The right way is with sessionStorage, because when your browser is closed the variable will be deleted

```
 // Save data to sessionStorage
sessionStorage.setItem('key', 'value');

// Get saved data from sessionStorage
var data = sessionStorage.getItem('key');

// Remove saved data from sessionStorage
sessionStorage.removeItem('key')
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/sessionStorage

Answer (score 0):

The sessionStorage object is similar to localStorage object, except that it stores the data for only one session. The data is deleted when the user closes the specific browser tab. As per your requirement, this seems more suitable.

Example :

```
if (sessionStorage.clickcount) {
      sessionStorage.clickcount = Number(sessionStorage.clickcount) + 1;
} else {
      sessionStorage.clickcount = 1;
}
document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = "You have clicked the button " + sessionStorage.clickcount + " time(s) in this session.";
```